# string function C++ return empty when run on objective C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I try to write function c++ return a string and run it on objective C++, but I always receives  empty string instead of normal string. Please help me.
In file `Greeting.cpp`:

```
#include "Greeting.hpp"

string getVersion() {
  string version = "Hello C++";
  return version;
}
```

In file `Greeting.hpp`

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string getVersion();
```

In file `CoreWrapper.h`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#undef NO
#undef YES
#import "Greeting.hpp"
#endif

@interface CoreWrapper : NSObject

+ (NSString*) greeting;

@end
```

In file `CoreWrapper.mm`

```
#import "CoreWrapper.h"
@implementation CoreWrapper

+ (NSString*) greeting {
    NSString *sAppleString = @(getVersion().c_str());
    NSLog(@"Message == %@", sAppleString);
    return sAppleString;
}

@end
```

`sAppleString` always return empty string . I dont know why ?

Comment: `getVersion()` returns temporary, which gets destroyed immediately. After that the pointer got from `c_str()` becomes dangled.

Comment: You don't need `#ifdef __cplusplus
#undef NO
#undef YES
#import "Greeting.hpp"
#endif` part. Import "Greeting.hpp" in CoreWrapper.mm

Comment: @songyuanyao no, it doesn't, string is copied

Comment: I can't reproduce, it works on my side

Comment: If I remove `#ifdef __cplusplus #undef NO #undef YES #import "Greeting.hpp" ` It will throw errors `string` file not found ?

Comment: `#import "Greeting.hpp"` in `CoreWrapper.mm`

Comment: Thanks move to `CoreWrapper.mm ` is better but I still receive a null string.

Comment: I try to `    NSLog(@"Message == %@", getVersion().c_str());` but app force close

Comment: It's expectable, because c_str isn't NSObject :)

Comment: So the string is empty or null?

Comment: string is still empty

Comment: Try with debugger step by step find out which part of your code returns empty strings. Yours example is working for me, may be you have global variable with same name, or may be you have two implementations of `getVersion`

Answer (score 0):

To test your code, I've had to add the following to `CoreWrapper.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Else `NSString` and `NSObject` are unavailable.

With that done, the code compiles, and when I call it from `main()` using:

```
    NSString* str = [CoreWrapper greeting];
    NSLog(@"main: %@", str);
```

I get the expected output:

```
Message == Hello C++
main: Hello C++
```

So to me it seems like you've got an issue in a larger program, reduced the code down to what you thought was causing the problem, but it's not actually that.

A few extra notes:

- You might want to move `#import "Greeting.hpp"` to the `CoreWrapper.mm` file and keep your header file clean of C++ code. Conditional compilation can hide bugs.
- I'm not sure what your `#undef` directives are about, they should not be necessary.

Comment: The problem is I call NSString* str = [CoreWrapper greeting] on `.m` file. Example I have xx.m file , then I import `CoreWrapper .h` , so I still receive empty string. Do you use `NSString *sAppleString = @(getVersion().c_str()); ` ?